# Mandril Inbound Web-hook suddenly not receiving emails

Tags: mandrill

One of our applications use mandrill with a web hook. It was working fine and suddenly it does not receive inbound emails. I am seeing Mx record on AWS and all the tests are working fine.

But we don't receive emails. I have emailed mandrill support but they didn't respond.

Does anybody know how to debug such an issue?

I tried sending emails they are not bouncing back nor they are not received in mandril inbound box.

Thanks for any help.